# Adding a working ipv6 nat to an existing ipv4 nat

Tags: ipv6, nat

I like to add ipv6 to an existing an working ipv4 nat. It is a proxmox host and the clients are vms.

I tried to get it working by adding corresponding files on the nat device (proxmox host).
The file /etc/network/interfaces looks now like this:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
  address 124.202.254.99
  netmask 255.255.255.192
  gateway 126.202.254.129
  up route add -net 116.202.254.128 netmask 255.255.255.192 gw 116.202.254.129 dev eno1

iface eno1 inet6 static
  address 2a01:4f8:543:4122::12
  netmask 64
  gateway fe80::1

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  192.168.20.1
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '192.168.20.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '192.168.20.0/24' -o eno1 -j MASQUERADE
        post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
        post-down iptables -t raw -D PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
        # Port 80 (http)
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.200
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.200

        # Port 443 (https)
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.200
        post-down iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.20.200


iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address fcc9::1
        netmask 64
        bridge_ports none
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
     # Port 80 (http)  - hex c8 is 200 decimal!
        post-up   ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination fcc9::c8
        post-down ip6tables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination fcc9::c8

        # Port 443 (https) - hex c8 is 200 decimal!
        post-up   ip6tables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination fcc9::c8
        post-down ip6tables -t nat -D PREROUTING -i eno1 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination fcc9::c8
```

The client's /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug ens18
iface ens18 inet static
    address 192.168.20.200/24
    gateway 192.168.20.1
    # dns-* options are implemented by the resolvconf package, if installed
    # put nameservers in /etc/resolv.conf

iface ens18 inet6 static
    address fcc9::c8
    netmask 64
    gateway fcc9::1
```

On proxmox host, I ran `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1`

I can ping6 from proxmox host to every host on the internet that has ipv6.
I can also ping from client to `fcc9::1`, and also to `2a01:4f8:543:4122::12`, but I can't ping `google.com` from client. The address is resolved correctly.